# Looking for an Android 3d engine that able to simulate coin flipping?

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es, 3d

I am planning an app with a "coin flipping simulation" function(Activity) in an Android phone. I am new to 3D (OpenGL) here , and I know there will be a lot of efforts to build from scratch. So , I am looking for an existing 3D engine , which is able to simulate :

1. Coin flip and drop , with G-Sensor , so that users can shake/wave his phone to see the coins flipping.
2. Able to get which coin is up or down after the coins drop.
3. Able to assign how many coins are in the 'hands(or virtual table)'
4. Able to render different textures to the coins
5. The simulation must be the more realistic the better. So there should be a built-in gravity algorithm.

OpenSource is welcome , and Commercial is acceptable too.

Can someone give me some suggestions , or existing libraries , or algorithms (gravity ...)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[Ten Open Source Android (2D or 3D) Game Engine for Android Developers](http://www.cuteandroid.com/ten-open-source-android-2d-or-3d-game-engine-for-android-developers)

Answer (score 0):

Just for 3D have a look at [Min3D](http://code.google.com/p/min3d/).